# What are the downsides of not using the monitor's native resolution?

Tags: display, resolution

I have a LED monitor, which is used with a computer running Windows. What are the downsides of not using the monitor's native resolution?

Comment: @random how do you want to me to make the question less broad? (the other 2 folks didn't close vote for 'too broad')

Comment: Same as asking what are the advantages of using the native resolution. What is the reason for doing so, what are you seeing, what do you want to workaround on it? Make it less "what could possibly happen" and more "This is what's happening, what can I do?"

Comment: @random Prevention is better than cure. I posted the question on Quora: https://www.quora.com/What-are-the-downsides-of-not-using-the-monitors-native-resolution . Did you see http://superuser.com/search?q=+what+are+the+advantages+of+ ? looks like there are a few other questions you should close.

Comment: I'm voting to reopen this, it seems like it's possible to write a long answer but doesn't seem broad to me.

Comment: You're right, it should have been closed as an opinion piece

Comment: @random Then we go back to my comment that got deleted (why did you delete it?): why is it opinion based? If an image look blurred, do you count it as subjective?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some monitors and/or display adaptors will stretch the image to fill the monitor's native resolution. Depending on how well they do so, you may not notice anything except a slight loss of sharpness. If this stretching is done badly, you will see entire lines of pixels doubled, distorting text and sharp curved or diagonal lines.

Other monitors and/or adaptors will just display the lower resolution image with a black border around it, wasting some of the size of the monitor but not distorting the image.

In any case, there isn't much reason to use less than the native resolution of the monitor, but it isn't going to damage anything.

(None of this applies to old-school CRTs or other monitors with variable pixel size (pitch) and thus no native resolution. Also, some CRTs could actually be physically damaged by feeding them signals beyond their capabilities.)

Answer (score 6):

The image will look blurred, which can strain your eyes on the long run. But it won't harm the display itself.